# How do I get <pre style="overflow: scroll; height : 150px" > to display at particular scroll line?

Tags: html

I need for the code section shown in pre to point to a particular line number.  If there are 100 lines in pre I want what is shown to be line 51 for right in the center of the 150px box.

Answer (score 13):

Try this (for 10 lines):

```html
<pre style="width: 300px; height: 10pc; overflow-y: scroll;">
  1
  2
  3
  4
  5
  6
  7
  8
  9
  10
  11
  12
</pre>
```

Note "pc" instead "px"

Comment: 7 years later ... an explanation of how this is supposed to work would be nice. BTW: `pc` is pica: One pica. `1pc` = `12pt` = 1/6th of `1in`. See [CSS values and units](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Introduction_to_CSS/Values_and_units) and [`<length>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length) on MDN. But like pixels, this is also an absolute length unit (`1px` = 1/96th of `1in`), and as such there are many situations where this probably does not work.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using [scrollTop](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/) in jQuery:

```
$("#code").scrollTop(topPosition);
```

where `scrollPosition` is "the number of pixels that are hidden from view above the scrollable area".

The difficulty is working out what this value should be. If you know the height of each line (which you can set using `font-size` in CSS, you could use:

```
topPosition = lineHeight * (lineNumber - 1);
```

But then you want the specified line to be in the middle of the container, so perhaps:

```
topPosition = lineHeight * (lineNumber - 1) - 70;
if (topPosition < 0) topPosition = 0;
```

I would play around with this and see if you can make it work. :)

Answer (score 0):

To achieve that, you need a fixed line height for your `pre` element. For 150px height I suggest 15px for `line-height` and 11px for `font-size`. This will ensure 10 lines in your scrollable area.

The rest is some math and using `scrollTop` property.

example:

```
function goToLine(centeredLine){
    var pre = document.getElementById('scrollablePre');
    pre.scrollTop = (centeredLine - 5) * 15;
};
```