# Vertical scrollbar for long functions with knitr slides

Tags: css, knitr, r-markdown, remarkjs, xaringan

Is it possible to make vertical scrollbar for long functions with knitr slides (using [xaringan](https://slides.yihui.name/xaringan/) custom style)? I was trying some options based on this previous question [How to make vertical scrollbar appear in RMarkdown code chunks (html view)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41135085/how-to-make-vertical-scrollbar-appear-in-rmarkdown-code-chunks-html-view) but no idea how to do it only for long functions (which height goes out of the frame). Any advice is more than welcome.

````
---
title: "title"
subtitle: "subtitle"
author: "author"
date: "2017"
output:
  xaringan::moon_reader:
    lib_dir: libs
    css: ["default", "style.css"]
    nature:
      highlightStyle: zenburn
      highlightLines: true
      countIncrementalSlides: false
---

```{r , echo=FALSE, include=FALSE}
library(knitr)
opts_chunk$set(fig.align='center', message=TRUE, error=TRUE, warning=TRUE, tidy=TRUE, comment = "##", echo = TRUE, dev='svg')
options(width=65)
```

```{r}
fu <- function(x){
  x
  x
  x
  x
  x
  x
  x
  x
  x
  x
  x
  x
  x
  x
  x
  x
  x
  x
}
```
````

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried the solution from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35237862/best-way-to-handle-overflowing-reveal-js-slide)

```
.scrollable-slide {
    height: 800px;
    overflow-y: auto !important;
}
```

Comment: Something similar works well with xaringan, but only if I enclose the long code with the specification, not as a class for complete slides. Therefore, I opened a new [Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67750561/vertically-scrollable-code-with-rstudio-and-xaringan).

Answer (score 2):

In your `style.css`, create a class that define y overflow as scroll and the desired height of the div (see this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7717929/how-do-i-get-pre-style-overflow-scroll-height-150px-to-display-at-parti) as a reference)

```
.pre {
  height: 10pc;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Then apply that css class to the code block:

````
.pre[
```{r}
fu <- function(x){
  x
  x
  x
  x
  x
  x
  x
  x
  x
  x
  x
  x
  x
  x
  x
  x
  x
  x
}
```
]
````

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert with CSS so can't guarantee that this is a robust solution, but adding max-height and overflow-y to the styling of code blocks seems to work well. Adjust the max-height as necessary, 200px is fairly short and only used to demonstrate how it works:

```
<style>
pre.sourceCode {
    max-height: 200px;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
</style>
```

I'm not sure if the class name for code blocks changes with different output formats, I was using `slidy_presentation` as I didn't have your renderer installed so you may have to check the class on your output.

Comment: It did not work. Maybe it has to be with the class on the output. The style I am using is [example.css](https://github.com/yihui/xaringan/blob/master/inst/rmarkdown/templates/xaringan/resources/example.css). How can I check the output class?