# Vertically scrollable code with RStudio and xaringan

Tags: html, css, r, rstudio, xaringan

I am currently preparing html slides for an **R** modelling workshop, for which I use the awesome  **xaringan** package for **R**. It is based on [remark.js](https://remarkjs.com/). Compared to ioslides and slidy, it does much better suit my expectations. I am absolutely excited! One feature that I missed, are scrollable "long slides". Here I leave of course the "slides"  paradigm towards a mix between slides and ordinary web pages, but I find this didactically attractive to explain complex content and code. This style worked well with **slidy**, and I found also some hints how to enable scrollable code in **xaringan**.

Here I use the following CSS (found in a [related post at SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45990974/vertical-scrollbar-for-long-functions-with-knitr-slides)):

```
.scrollable {
  height: 80%;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

and then in an RMarkdown code chunk something like:

````
.scrollable[
  
```{r}
foo <- function() {
  cat("nothing\n")
}

foo()
foo()
foo()
foo()
foo()
foo()
foo()
foo()
foo()
foo()

## some comments ...
# ...
foo()
```

]
````

#### Long slides

Here I mean web-pages that can be scrolled down, but still stay embeded in a slide show.

[image: long slide]

#### Code Example

An example with scrollable code **within a slide** is found here:

- Code: https://github.com/dynamic-R/hacking-limnology/blob/main/docs/test.Rmd
- Demo: https://dynamic-r.github.io/hacking-limnology/test.html#3

It works partly, but I am not yet completely satisfied:

- I would prefer true "long slides" instead of scrollable text.
- Instead of enclosing parts with `.scrollable[]` I would prefer a class for complete slides
- It works only with Chrome, Edge (and the Infinite Moon Reader of RStudio), but not with Firefox. **Edit:** absolute `heigt` works with Firefox (Thanks to comment of @Waldi)

The CSS approach was taken from [a related post at SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45990974/vertical-scrollbar-for-long-functions-with-knitr-slides), that contains also links to further approaches (partly with additional JavaScript), but I was not able to get them running.

#### The Question

Any ideas, how to:

- define a **xaringan** slide class with scrollable content or
- to define slides as true "long slides", i.e. long html pages

where "slide class with scrollable content" or a "long-slide" class may be defined like:

```
---
class: scrollable-slide
```

similar to:

```
---
layout: false
class: inverse, middle, center
```

found in https://github.com/yihui/xaringan/wiki/Slide-layouts

Comment: Note that `.scrollable` also works with Firefox if you set a fixed `height` instead of a percentage.

Comment: Thanks, a small but indeed important hint. I remember that Firefox seemed to work in one case, but I made too much trial and error ...

Comment: What do you mean with xaringan slide class? Do you mean the [remark class property?](https://github.com/gnab/remark/wiki/Markdown#class)

Comment: I mean a class definition that can be placed below the `---` slide separator. Thank you for the comment, I edited the question accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`remark.js` was not made with scrollable slides in mind, which means that it is not possible to implement scrolling without a major feature addition to `remark.js` or breaking certain `remark.js` features.

If you are willing to break some features, the easiest way I can think of to hack in scrollable slides is by altering the `y-overflow` of the `.remark-slide-scaler` class. All we have to do is add the following CSS:

```css
.remark-slide-scaler {
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

To include this CSS you can write it to a file, say `scrollable.css`, and include it in the `xaringan` config block like so:

```yaml
title: "Scrollable slides"
output:
  xaringan::moon_reader:
    css: ["default", "scrollable.css"]
```

This CSS will add a scroll bar to all slides which have content that is longer than the slide itself.

### Things that break

#### Scrolling through slides

By default `remark.js` allows you to scroll from one slide to the next or previous one. However, when we have a scrollbar on a slide, we would like to heve this behaviour disabled.

The proper way to solve this is to write implement some functionality in `remark.js` that disables and enables the default scrolling behaviour at appropriate times.

An easy way is to simply disable scrolling through slides. We can do so by adding `scroll: false` to the `navigation` block in our `nature` block of our `xaringan` config:

```yaml
title: "Scrollable slides"
output:
  xaringan::moon_reader:
    css: ["default", "scrollable.css"]
    nature:
      navigation:
# Disable scrolling through slides to
# allow scrolling in slides
        scroll: false
```

#### Page numbers

Page numbers are positioned at the bottom of the slide frame, but stick to the bottom of the slide content. This means that when you scroll down your scrollable slide, the page number scrolls up as well.

[image: Showing how slide numbers scroll up]

To fix this properly, we would have to change how `remark.js` renders the content. A common solution is something like [this](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/examples/sticky-footer/), which involves having the main content in a separate container from the footer. This footer would contain the page numbers.

An easy solution is hiding the page numbers. We can do so by adding the following to our `scrollable.css`:

```css
.remark-slide-number {
    display: none;
}
```

#### Cloning

`remark.js` has a feature called "cloning" which lets you have several instances of the slides opened, but all synced to the same page. So when one instance goes to the next slide, all other slides do so as well. This unfortunately does not work as expected for our scrolling slides. `remark.js` is not able to register how far the page has been scrolled down, so it cannot communicate that to its clones. This means that on one instance you may have scrolled down all the way, but the other instances will still be stuck at the top of the content. An easy solution is to simply not use this feature.

#### Printing (not tested)

I have not tested this, but I can imagine the scrolling slide mucking up printing. Either the content will get truncated, or the long page will get printed in its entire length, possibly overlapping other things on the page. An easy solution here is to simply not print the slides.

There may be more features, like printing, that may or may not break by hacking in scrolling slides.

### Conclusion

To summarise, if you are able to live with limited functionality, you can hack in scrolling slides by first creating a file `scrollable.css`, containing:

```css
.remark-slide-scaler {
    overflow-y: auto;
}

.remark-slide-number {
    display: none;
}
```

And secondly include `scrollable.css` as well as `scroll: false` in your `xaringan` config. I have included a sample slideset below to illustrate.

```
---
title: "Scrollable slides"
output:
  xaringan::moon_reader:
    css: ["default", "scrollable.css"]
    nature:
      navigation:
# Disable scrolling through slides to
# allow scrolling in slides
        scroll: false
---
class: center

# First a normal short slide

Some content here
---
class: scrollable-slide

# A

# long

# slide

# that

# requires

# scrolling

# on

# my

# system
---
# End slide
```

### Other options

If you don't have that many slides that need to be long, you could opt to make a handout. If you make this with `rmarkdown`, it would make the source files of the handouts very similar to the source file of the slides, would allow for exporting to different formats (like html), and would let you use all of `remark.js`'s features.

Another option, if you *really* need this and can make a good case why this is useful to others as well, would be to make a feature request at the `remark.js` [GitHub page](https://github.com/gnab/remark) for scrollable slides.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this works well. I can reproduce also the issues described above, that can be tolerated for my purpose. (1) Mouse scrolling is disabled anyway. (2) Page numbers can be considered as a feature, not a bug, because one see where a page would normally end. (3) Cloning: nice to have for speaker notes, but not essential in this use case. (4) Printing: does not work, but it's indeed easy to make a printable handout - this is something I like anyway. Thanks for the reminder ;-)

O.k., there are still some issues and wishes, but I am now even more excited about xarigan/remark.js.