# Switch slide number display on and off in RMarkdown xaringan / reveal.js slides

Tags: css, r, r-markdown, reveal.js, xaringan

I am currently preparing html slides for a workshop, for which I use the [**xaringan**](https://slides.yihui.org/xaringan/) package for R, that is based on **remark.js**. Here the slides are created with RMarkdown. This works well, but for some reasons (explained in a [former SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67750561/vertically-scrollable-code-with-rstudio-and-xaringan)) I want to switch off slide numbers on some pages, while keeping them visible on most others.

Until now, I am able to switch **all** slide numbers on and off either in a personal css style file or with an inline chunk:

````
```{css slide-number-off}
.remark-slide-number {
  display: none;
}
```

```{css slide-number-on}
.remark-slide-number {
  display: inline;
}
```
````

But I have not been able to switch page numbers on and off for **individual** slides.

Answer (score 1):

A quick trick, is to include this property within an inverse class:

```
.inverse .remark-slide-number {
  display: none;
}
```